# Git: How do I find which commit deleted a line?

Tags: git

I know I added a line in a particular commit and can see it in a private GitHub account. In my current branch it isn't in there any more. How do I find which commit removed it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `git blame` with the `--reverse` option:

```
$ git blame --reverse START.. file.ext
```

where START is a revision which still contains the line in question.

Comment: The then following commit is the one that removes the line.

Comment: It would be good to add what this does, namely showing each line with the last commit on which it still existed.